# Wordpress Rewrite URL with params

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have the following url and I'm using the `type` parameter in a `WP_Query` to generate a list of posts.

`http://wordpress.dev/en-ie/category-holiday-deals/?type=city-breaks`

I want to rewrite the url so it looks like this:

`http://wordpress.dev/en-ie/holiday-deals/city-breaks`

but I want to be able to use the `type` param still.

I have the following that's capturing the query vars:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'sd_query_vars', 10, 1);

function sd_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'type';
    $vars[] = 'destination';
    return $vars;
}
```

but I can't figure out how to rewrite the URL.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I've had to handle redirects with WordPress, I have used a plug-in like [Rewrite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/). It gives you a nice interface to create rewrite rules.

I've found it's a lot easier than fiddling with the `.htaccess` file directly.